# Can you open documents in tabs in BBEdit?

Tags: bbedit

I've been using BBEdit for text editing on Mac and I really like it. However, whenever I open a new document it opens it in a new window, and I'd like it to open each new document in a tab like TextEdit or Notes do. Is there a way to do this in BBEdit? I'm also confused because sometimes BBEdit opens files in the "currently open documents" panel, allowing me to switch between them easily, which is what I'd like it to do all the time. Is this only for files in the same folder?

Also, if BBEdit can't do this, I'd appreciate suggestions for a plain text editor that both opens things in tabs and supports Markdown. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a setting in the "Application" preferences to control this: "Open documents into the front window when possible."

It's turned *on* by default, if you use "New => Text Window" on the File menu, you'll get a new window irrespective of the preference setting. (Use "New => Text Document" to create a new document in the sidebar of the front window.)

Otherwise, if the application is behaving inconsistently, `support@barebones.com` is available to help.

Comment: Ah, ok. I turned it back on and it seems to be working now. Thanks!